# how to have use own jade file for webpack?

Tags: html, pug, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm new to webpack and trying to figure out how to use my own html file in the webpack-dev-server, as well as my webpack build.

in my app.js I have:

`require('!jade!index.jade')`

but that does not make an `index.html` as I would expect. Instead, it seems at best I can get a string output of my html, which isn't what I want:

```
var jade = require('!jade!index.jade')
jade() //outputs my html
```

How do I get it to output an index.html file? How do I get the webpack-dev-server to use that html file?

I should also mention my jade file will likely reference stylus files

Comment: Depending on your use case, it may be better to create static HTML files directly from the jade file during development before it is served rather than using the jade file on the server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use [jade-html-loader](https://github.com/bline/jade-html-loader) with the following entry in `webpack.config.js`:

```
entry: ['./src/app.js', 'file?name=index.html!jade-html!./src/index.jade']
```

You will need

```
npm install --save-dev file-loader jade-html-loader jade
```

Comment: Don't you also have a configuration line in `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: This gives me a .html file containing `module.exports = "html here...";` - any ideas? (am using Jade by it's new name, Pug, now)

Comment: In fact.. I really can't see how this would work.  The HTML file is always going to in fact be a JS file, isn't it?