# How to code HTML with jade and webpack with hot reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, pug, webpack-dev-server

I'm new with `webpack`, trying to setup simple config to code HTML/CSS with `jade` templates, `PostCSS`, `hot reload` and serve HTML through `webpack-dev-server` to speed up coding experience.

So I will have multiple entry points, some `jade` files with includes, CSS, img, fonts, and other assets.

Any `webpack` config suggestions? Thanks.

I've tried `html-webpack-plugin`, with config like

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename:'page1.html',
    templateContent: function(templateParams, compilation) {
        var templateFile = path.join(__dirname, './src/page1.jade');
        compilation.fileDependencies.push(templateFile);
        return jade.compileFile(templateFile)();
    },
    inject: true,
})
```

It's working but no hot reload for jade includes, no css/img/font assets..

Then I found `indexhtml-webpack-plugin` but it seems to work only with HTML files, templates are not supported.

**Edit1:**

For now, I ended up with this `webpack.config.js`:

```js
var path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
    node_modules_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './index.js'],
        page2: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './page2.js'],
        //vendors: ['react', 'jquery'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '/'),
        libraryTarget: "umd"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        //new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors.js'),
        new webpack.dependencies.LabeledModulesPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        noParse: [
            new RegExp('^react$'),
            new RegExp('^jquery$'),
        ],
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/,    loader: "babel-loader", query: {optional: ["es7.classProperties"]}},
            { test: /\.html$/,  loader: "html" },
            { test: /\.jade$/,  loader: "jade" },
            { test: /\.css$/,   loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader" },
            { test: /\.woff$/,  loader: 'url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000&minetype=application/font-woff'},
            { test: /\.ttf$/,   loader: 'url-loader?prefix=font/'},
            { test: /\.eot$/,   loader: 'url-loader?prefix=font/'},
            { test: /\.svg$/,   loader: 'url-loader?prefix=font/'},
            { test: /\.png$/,   loader: "url-loader?prefix=img/&mimetype=image/png"},
            { test: /\.jpg$/,   loader: "url-loader?prefix=img/&mimetype=image/jpg"},
            { test: /\.gif$/,   loader: "url-loader?prefix=img/&mimetype=image/gif"}
        ],
    },
    postcss: function() {
        return {
          defaults: [
            require('autoprefixer')
          ]
        }
    }
}

Object.keys(module.exports.entry).forEach(function(page){

    if(page!=='vendors'){
        module.exports.plugins.push( new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: page+'.html',
            chunks: [page]
        }) );
    }
})
```

An `index.js` entry point looks like:

```js
import index from './templates/index.jade';
require('./css/index.css');
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  document.body.innerHTML = index();
}
```

This is working setup for me for HTML/CSS development for this moment.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your working setup! (you could also post it as a solution if you like)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) can take a template parameter, which can take an explicit loader (as seen in their documentation) or use the configured loaders:

```js
// webpack.config.js

var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jade$/,
        loader: 'jade'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.jade'
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Worked for me, ty!

Comment: Thanks, using it too from the moment they added template support(not supported when question was asked).

Answer (score 0):

There is a jade-html-loader. I'm about to try and set it up.

Thanks goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32312078

I'm new to webpack too, and am thinking the jade html loader is a more specific loader that does the same exact thing the html-loader does, but only for jade.

edit:
Meh, html-webpack-plugin